# piping seq to printf for number formatting

Tags: bash, printf, xargs, seq

I'm trying to print the following pattern using printf and seq:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
```

My problem is once I use:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs printf %04d
```

all my output is formatted into the same line likeso:

```
0000000100020003
```

I still can't get the hang of using xargs. How do I use it correctly in this case?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `printf` command does not output a line break if you don't ask it to. Try:

```
seq 0 10 | xargs printf '%04d\n'
```

Note that you can achieve the same with just `seq`, since it allows specifying a printf-style format:

```
seq -f %04g 0 10
```

Answer (score 16):

you don't need `printf` or `xargs`. `seq` has `-f` option:

```
kent$  seq -f '%04G' 10
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
0010
```

Answer (score 5):

```
seq 0 10 | xargs printf "%04d\n"
```

The original question is missing the newline character at the end of the `printf`.  Simply adding a newline character fixes the issue.

Comment: Please add some more explanation.

Comment: Done.  Though there is a better answer using the format on `seq`.